# Durable Functions Orchestrator template missing in Visual Studio 17.4 with .Net 7.0 SDK installed

Tags: azure-durable-functions, .net-7.0, azure-functions-isolated

I am running Visual Studio 17.4 on Windows 10 Pro and have installed the [.NET 7.0 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.100-windows-x64-installer)

I want to create a Durable Functions project, but I don't see the **Durable Functions Orchestrator** template in the list of templates when I try to add a New Azure Function to the project.

Here are the steps I followed (based on the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-visualstudio), which unfortunately only covers .NET 6 In-Process): When creating the project, I select '.NET 7.0 Isolated' as the Functions Worker and 'Empty' as the Function type (even though I would expect to see *Durable Function* as an option here...)
[Choose functions worker type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzfPC.png)

Once the empty project is created, I right-click on the project and select Add > New Azure Function...
[Add New Azure Function...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmnzQ.png)

I choose *Azure Function* as the type, and give it a name...

[Name the new function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADs3y.png)

...and then I would expect to see a template for *Durable Functions Orchestration* in the list of templates, but it is missing:

[Choose the function template...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Ef2.png)

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add extra templates via a NuGet package or something? I thought all relevant templates would be included in the SDK.

I have already tried running the SDK installer again, and choosing the Repair option. This seems to cause it to spend a lot longer checking everything than the original installation did, but still does not add the *Durable Functions Orchestrator* template.

Has anyone else experienced the same? (In  the meantime, I have [raised a case on GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/101865) for MS to update their documentation to cover .NET 7.0)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing Durable Functions Orchestration is not supported in .NET isolated. This is probably why it's not integrated in the template.
However a preview version is available, here is the documentation:

https://github.com/microsoft/durabletask-dotnet#durable-task-net-client-sdk